# use event on message bus to trigger suspended activity

Tags: elsa-workflows

newbie here.
Reading the docs I understand we can use an incoming HTTP request as a trigger to wake up a suspended activity.

In my case, the business trigger is the arrival of a message on a bus (from another system)…..

I thought of building out dedicated hosted service that just listens to messages arriving on the bus and invoke / trigger the respective activities....

Would I be following the suggested patterns if I do that ? It feels wrong as I'd be writing some custom external code rather than relying on the declarative approach usually described in the ELSA docs...

Any thoughts welcome..

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. Both patterns are great and in fact, the declarative approach *depends* on supporting infrastructure (such as hosted services).

For example, let's take the `HttpEndpoint` and `AzureServiceBusMessageReceived` activities.

Both of them require supporting infrastructure:

- *HttpEndpoint* depends on ASP.NET Core middleware to trigger workflows as HTTP requests come in
- *AzureServiceBusMessageReceived* depends on a hosted service that contains message workers to trigger the appropriate workflows.

For your case, you don't have to write your own hosted service if you can use one of the existing messaging activities, since it's already done for you.

At the same time, it's perfectly OK to just have your own hosted service that consumes messages and trigger workflows yourself. You could make it even a bit fancier by having your hosted service trigger business-specific activities.

For example, rather than triggering some low-level "message received" activity, you could trigger a "order created" activity if that is what the message is all about.

More details about implementing these types of activities can be found `https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/guides/guides-blocking-activities`.

As you already discovered, there are also examples in the repository `https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/tree/master/src/samples`.

Comment: wow... that is fantastic and relieved to see that my instinct in fact was aligned with actual implementation....

Answer (score 0):

I was only considering the Elsa Guides, but just discovered a whole list of additional samples in the Elsa-Core project itself.  In particular, there are several examples that seem to handle my use case (example Elsa.Samples.RabbitMqWorker)....